# How to access [details] inside array

Tags: php, arrays

How to access the value of an inside array in PHP?

```
Array
(
    [exists] => 1
    [detail] => Array
        (
            [memberDetailID] => 73
            [memberID] => 111
            [memberTitle] => Mr
        )

)
```

Comment: Without using a loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to add other column:

```
Array
(
    [exists] => 1
    [detail] => Array
        (
            [memberDetailID] => 73
            [memberID] => 111
            [memberTitle] => Mr
        )

)

$yourArray['detail']['memberID'];
```

[Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Array elements can be accessed using the array[key] syntax.

Example #6 Accessing array elements

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]);
var_dump($array[42]);
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
?>
```

Next time [search better](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask so basic question, [you need to put more effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Thanks buddy! You saved my time and solved my problem.